# How to restrict OS using specific memory locations in RAM?

Tags: grub2, ram, memory-card, memory-test

I have 6 GB of RAM, my RAM has a block of memory corrupt( 1MB of size).
When I tested it with memtest, it showed about a hundred thousand of errors in just a small part of it, starting from 5024.1 MB to 5024.9, I have heard about badram entry in grub.conf file, but it isn't possible to list all those errors in it and it also restricts my windows 10 OS to boot up.( I have a dual boot).
Due to this small corrupt block my programs keep on crashing now and then.
I want to know is there any way to restrict my OS us that corrupt memory location, or restrict using any memory beyond that 5024.0 MB mark?

Comment: Not specifically what you're looking for, but have you tried to limit the memory?  I'm unsure how memory is allocated, so not sure if this will help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484016/setting-limit-to-total-physical-memory-available-in-linux

Comment: Replacing the RAM is always an option....

Comment: Actually I brought new memory chip, and it went corrupt after few months.